# sqlsrv multiple arrays insert into SQL Server is there a better way?

Tags: php, arrays, sql-server, sqlsrv

What is a better way to have multiple arrays on `$params` for SQL Server. When I tried to combine array to `$params` I get an error of the web page not working. Need to add 4 separate rows of data to SQL Server. The code works but I wanted to combine the '$params' and send the rest of the code once.

```php
<?php
include_once '../dbcon1.php';
date_default_timezone_set('America/Phoenix');
$datetime_variable = new DateTime();
$datetime_formatted = date_format($datetime_variable, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
$unitnumber = $_POST['unitnumber'];
$username = $_POST['userid'];
$pos1 = $_POST['pos1'];
$pos2 = $_POST['pos2'];
$pos3 = $_POST['pos3'];
$pos4 = $_POST['pos4'];
$depth1 = $_POST['depth1'];
$depth2 = $_POST['depth2'];
$depth3 = $_POST['depth3'];
$depth4 = $_POST['depth4'];
$pressure1 = $_POST['pressure1'];
$pressure2 = $_POST['pressure2'];
$pressure3 = $_POST['pressure3'];
$pressure4 = $_POST['pressure4'];

$sql = "
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[tiresinspect] 
     ([date],[username],[unitnumber],[tirelocation],[depth],[psi]) 
  VALUES
     (?,?,?,?,?,?)
";

$params1 = array($datetime_formatted, $username, $unitnumber, $pos1, $depth1, $pressure1);
$params2 = array($datetime_formatted, $username, $unitnumber, $pos2, $depth2, $pressure2);
$params3 = array($datetime_formatted, $username, $unitnumber, $pos3, $depth3, $pressure3);
$params4 = array($datetime_formatted, $username, $unitnumber, $pos4, $depth4, $pressure4);

$stmt1 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params1);
$stmt2 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params2);
$stmt3 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params3);
$stmt4 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params4);
if( $stmt1 === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}else{
   
}
if( $stmt2 === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}else{
    
}
if( $stmt3 === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}else{
   
}
if( $stmt4 === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}else{
    header("Location: index.php?Submitted");
}

?>
```

Also tried to combine the `$params` this way and received an error.

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -15 [code] => -15 [2] => An invalid direction for parameter 1 was specified. SQLSRV_PARAM_IN, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT, and SQLSRV_PARAM_INOUT are valid values. [message] => An invalid direction for parameter 1 was specified. SQLSRV_PARAM_IN, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT, and SQLSRV_PARAM_INOUT are valid values. ) )

```
$params1 = array(array(
$datetime_formatted, $username, $unitnumber, $pos1, 
$depth1, $pressure1),
array($datetime_formatted, $username, $unitnumber, $pos2, 
$depth2, $pressure2),
array($datetime_formatted, $username, $unitnumber, $pos3, 
$depth3, $pressure3),
array($datetime_formatted, $username, $unitnumber, $pos4, 
$depth4, $pressure4));
```

Comment: Lots of ways to do this, but the most sensible way is probably just to write a function that accepts your params. Ex. `function saveTiresInspect($datetime, $username, $unit, $position, $depth, $pressure) {...}` and then call your function from whenever you need it. Ex. `saveTiresInspect(...)`.

Comment: What is the error message? It's probably a conversion error (try to use unambiguous datetime format: (`yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss`)): `$datetime_formatted = date_format($datetime_variable, 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s');`.